# How can i use telegram lib to auth and send message to my phone number in java?

Tags: java, spring, api, github, telegram

Im trying to connect my java project to my phone number, i already have the app_id and the hash generated by Telegram.
Im using https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi this library imported to my pom project, but im not understanding how can i use the app_id, ip and hash that telegram generated for me to authenticate and send a simple "hi" message.

```
    AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo(appId,"devicemodel","systemversion","appversion","langcode");
    TelegramApi api = new TelegramApi(AbsApiState, AppInfo, ApiCallback);
```

I can initialize the variable AppInfo , i have de app_id, do i need to put real data(devicemodel,systemversion,appversion,langcode) to the rest of the required fields?

How can i intialize the Variables AbsApiState and ApiCallback ?

I searched many documentation and examples on the Internet, it is really simple to create a bot to communicate but i want to send message user to user, not bot to user in the future.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The library you have mentioned is for sending messages from bots you own. On the other hand `api_id` and `api_hash` are used for client apps for real users. It seems that you want to send a message as user, not a bot. **You can't do it with this library.**

I suggest using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) which is the best library I've ever used for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i was posting the wrong library, i updated to the correct dependency that i am using, when i searched the best ways to do it,i found telethon but its in python, do you know if its available to java?

Comment: Unfortunately, Telethon is not available in Java. I have not found any good Java library for this use case so far.